# Google Cloud VPN with multiple on-premises networks

Tags: vpn, google-compute-engine

I have a project on GCP and I want to setup site-to-site VPN between this project and multiple geographical branches.

I successfully setup VPN between Cloud VPN and one of the branches.

The problem is when I try to setup the VPN between the cloud VPN and the remaining branches ... Cloud VPN will not allow me to use the same Static IP address that I used in the first branch.

Is there a way in Google Cloud VPN that will allow me to setup site-to-site VPN between each branch and Cloud VPN using only one Static IP?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried tinc or Softether VPN? use one of those to build a single cross-site VPN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted GCP support and got my issue fixed using the following steps:

After setting up the first VPN Gateway, do these steps for each one of the remaining branches:

1. Goto your VPN in your web console.
2. In the VPN page, click "Google VPN Gateways".
3. Click your desired gateway.
4. On the page, click "add tunnel".
5. Then a page will pop up same as to setup a VPN tunnel, In there, you can configure your new branch setup.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud VPN cannot connect to multiple on-premises VPN gateways that share a single public IP address. You need to have different external static IP address each to connect with your other branches. And also you need to create different VPN tunnels to connect to your branches separately. This [document](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview) has more information about cloud VPN for different scenarios.

As the feature is currently not supported, you can create a feature request on Google public issue tracker. This [document](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) has details about how to create a feature request.

Comment: It seems it will work in GCP, check my answer.